# Detecting HTTPRequest failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I have used the following code in order to send large number of HTTPRequests and as many of the calls are not successful, I want to detect them and save them in a new list ( UnsuccessfulURLsPhase1 ) and send them again.

Unfortunately when the HTTPRequest fails to be sent, the exception doesn't happen and I can not add the url to the new list.

Any hints is appreciated.

```
private static async Task CallURLAsync(string url)
{
    try
    {
        var content = new MemoryStream();
        var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        using (WebResponse response = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())
        {
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        UnsuccessfulURLsPhase1.Add(url);
        Console.WriteLine("\nException raised!");
        Console.WriteLine("\nMessage:{0}", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check the response code also and find out if http request was successful or no. HTTP status 200 means its good. if(p.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.OK)
            { }

Comment: @sumeetkumar, Thank you, would you please provide your code when using GetResponse Async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
        var content = new MemoryStream();
            var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");

            using (WebResponse response = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                if(res.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    //your code
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, in order to check if the receiver receives the request, I developed a test program, but when sending the request using your mentioned code, it shows that all the calls are ok but I don't know why the receiver missed few of them. Is there a solution to find them out too( I have to leave the office and will check your response later)

Comment: not sure you might need to log them and put it here we can see

Comment: @summetkumar, for testing successful receiving request, I wrote a simple application like below in the page_load that count less than the sender count, and its strange why in this case the sender wont receive the failure response.              
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                counter1++;
                txtCounter.Text = counter1.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\nException raised!");
        }